# How do I get Rythymbox Music Player to omit the Oracle Java JDK binary from the playlists?

Tags: java, music-player

Rythymbox Music Player finds the Oracle Java JDK compressed file, which is a `.bin` and automatically puts it in a playlist.  If you delete the item from Rythymbox the file system is modified in that the JDK gets deleted.  This is very annoying because then I have to download the JDK again in order to keep it handy for server deployments.  I want to omit the JDK from the playlist but I want to keep the file.  How do I prevent this file from showing up in the playlist?

**Edit** Note that the playlist is not merely a view of what can potentially be played. If you delete the file from the playlist, the file actually gets deleted from the file system which might not be what you want.

Comment: Where is your Rhythmbox looking for music?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on a music file such as a `.mp3`. Select `Properties` and in the `Open With` tab change the default music player to `Movie Player`. Now when you double-click a similar file, it will not invoke Rythymbox and not have to assemble the Rythymbox playlist.